# How should I configure/rewrite CakePHP's htaccess for openlitespeed based server?

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, cakephp, litespeed

Here are the htaccess codes that CakePHP uses:-

I want to rewrite them/ convert them so that they run on my openlitespeed server. They work perfectly fine on a standard apache server.

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule    ^$ app/webroot/    [L]
RewriteRule    (.*) app/webroot/$1 [L]
</IfModule>    


<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule    ^$    webroot/    [L]
RewriteRule    (.*) webroot/$1    [L]
</IfModule>


<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php [QSA,L]
</IfModule>
```

Comment: Here is another one which I am personally using with the code..<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
   
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]
</IfModule>

Answer (score 1):

Simply add rewrite rules in Context of the virtual host you want. 
Add static **context** of the virtual host 
Parameters of context:
 - **URl** = `/` 
 - **Location** = default path e.g. `/usr/local/lsws/Example/html/`
 - **Accessible** =`Yes` 
 - **Enable Rewrite** = `Yes` 
 - **Rewrite Rules**=

```
RewriteRule    ^(.*)$ app/webroot/    [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php [QSA,L]
```

You can still put all your original rules to rewrite. 
I just put one rule `RewriteRule    ^(.*)$ app/webroot/    [L]` because I don't understand why need other rules. `webroot/` and `webroot/$1` seem never be matched.

```
RewriteRule    ^$ app/webroot/    [L]
RewriteRule    (.*) app/webroot/$1 [L]
RewriteRule    ^$    webroot/    [L]
RewriteRule    (.*) webroot/$1    [L]
```